# PL-SQL cursor that increments the salary of employees of I.T. Dept. by 20% in MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have to update all the employees of IT dept with 20% increased salary.
in MySQL workbench.

Create the following table:
Emp(E_ID, E_Name, E_Dept, E_Salary)

Insert appropriate data into Emp table.
The attribute E_Dept contains values like ( I.T. , Accounts, Sales)..
Write a PL-SQL cursor that increments the salary of employees of I.T. Dept. by 20%.

I wrote the query,

```
    create procedure up()
     begin

     DECLARE  v_employee_id INT;
         enter code hereDECLARE  v_salary      NUMERIC(8,2);
      DECLARE  v_last_emp    INT DEFAULT 0;

delcare emp_cur cursor for select empid,salary from employee where dept = IT for update;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET  v_last_emp=1;
START TRANSACTION;

open emp_cur;
emp_loop: LOOP

fetch emp_cur into v_employee_id, v_salary;
if v_last_emp then
leave emp_loop;
end if

update employee set salary = salary + salary * 0.20 where current of emp_cur;

end loop emp_loop;
close emp_cur;
set v_last_emp =0;
end;
```

Comment: PL/SQL only exists for Oracle so I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use cursor for this, this is basic SQL. Simply do the following, I added single quotes for `dept` filter, assuming this is a text field, but if not, adjust accordingly:

```
UPDATE employee SET salary = 1.2 * salary WHERE dept = 'IT';
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but there is a condition to use the cursor only

Comment: Ok, but it makes no sense. Cursors are very "anti-SQL", not efficient, because they loop through records. To update all rows like you mentioned, a simple UPDATE is the way to go in SQL world.

Comment: understood thanks but this is my college assignment
:===
Create the following table: 
Emp(E_ID, E_Name, E_Dept, E_Salary) 
Insert appropriate data into Emp table. 
The attribute E_Dept contains values like ( I.T. , Accounts, Sales).. 
Write a PL-SQL cursor that increments the salary of employees of I.T. Dept. by 20%.

Comment: ok, I had tried different logic but didn't get desired output.

Comment: maybe this helps you, just replace salary + 5000 with salary * 1.2: https://www.javatpoint.com/pl-sql-cursor

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to run this as procedure or loop

But you have some problem in your code

```
    create procedure up()
     begin

     DECLARE  v_employee_id INT;
         #enter code here
    DECLARE  v_salary      NUMERIC(8,2);
      DECLARE  v_last_emp    INT DEFAULT 0;

    declare emp_cur cursor for select empid,salary from employee where dept = 'IT' for update;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET  v_last_emp=1;
    START TRANSACTION;

open emp_cur;
    emp_loop: LOOP

        fetch emp_cur into v_employee_id, v_salary;
        if v_last_emp then
        leave emp_loop;
        end if;

        UPDATE employee 
        SET 
            salary = salary + (salary * 0.20)
        WHERE
            empid = v_employee_id;

    end loop emp_loop;
close emp_cur;
set v_last_emp =0;
end;
```